# Geocoding - map not centering on users location

Tags: javascript, html, web, geocoding

I'm having a problem where my map slides out from a tab and at the moment it is supposed to be centering on the users location, see jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/uADHv/2/

From what I understand the line:

```
center: coords,
```

should be centering the map on the users current location but is showing a random location which is close to the actual location but far enough away so that it isn't visible on the map.

Also could anyone who looks at the jsfiddle link post where the map is centering on, i'm curious to whether it will be somewhere close to where they are or if it will center in the same place for everyone.

Thanks

Comment: For me it centered in Warsaw, Poland which is correct - that's where my internet provider is registered.

Comment: Was that where the marker was?

Comment: Yes, marker was in the center of the map.

Comment: ok thanks, interesting that it doesn't center for me